# Row And Column Major Solidity

Tags: multidimensional-array, ethereum, solidity

I'm curious to know for a multi-dimension array in Solidity, are the data stored as a row-major or column major order.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in **row-major** order. This is valid for all arrays in `memory` and `calldata` locations, and for fixed-size arrays in `storage`.

One exception: Dynamic-size arrays in `storage` are accessible using a hash of their variable storage slot ID and indexes. So the rows might not be consequent. But the values are still stored in row-major.

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    uint[2][2] public fixedArray;
    uint[][] public dynamicArray;

    constructor() {
        fixedArray[0][0] = 1;
        fixedArray[0][1] = 2;
        fixedArray[1][0] = 3;
        fixedArray[1][1] = 4;

        // workaround - cannot resize in-memory dynamic-size arrays
        // so we declare a "dynamic array with predefined length" in memory
        uint[] memory dynamicArrayNested1 = new uint[](2);
        dynamicArrayNested1[0] = 5;
        dynamicArrayNested1[1] = 6;
        dynamicArray.push(dynamicArrayNested1);
        uint[] memory dynamicArrayNested2 = new uint[](2);
        dynamicArrayNested2[0] = 7;
        dynamicArrayNested2[1] = 8;
        dynamicArray.push(dynamicArrayNested2);
    }
}
```

**Storage debug:**

Fixed-size array:
[image: Fixed-size array]

Dynamic-size array:

- First value is size of the top array (== 2)
- Second value is size of the first nested array (== 2)
- Followed by values of the first nested array
- Then there's size of the second nested array (== 2)
- And finally values of the second nested array

[image: Dynamic-size array]